I have an Error "class cannot be cast to class....." in Anylogic Database
I have the following problem: I have not changed anything on my model, but I still get the following error message and nothing works anymore. Does anyone have any tips?The Error](https://i.sstatic.net/CbqYBJSr.png)
I have started the model from scratch several times, rebuilt the table and also reinstalled anylogic.

show the query you are making.. otherwise impossible to help

did you accidentally delete/corrupt your dbase?
